# How many fields are matching in a row

Tags: mysql, row, match

I'm looking for any ideas, how can I count the number of matching fields between every rows for two different tables in mysql.

Let's say table A is.

```
| ABC1    | ABC2    | ABC3    | ABC4    | ABC5    | LINE_A   |
| a       | b       | c       | d       | e       | A1       |
| f       | g       | h       | i       | j       | A2       |
| k       | l       | m       | n       | o       | A3       |
| p       | q       | r       | s       | t       | A4       |
| x       | y       | z       | u       | v       | A5       |
```

table B is:

```
| BBC1    | BBC2    | BBC3    | BBC4    | BBC5    | LINE_B  |
| a       | d       | f       | k       | o       | B1      |
| f       | k       | l       | p       | q       | B2      |
```

Result should be:

```
B1.A1: 2 ('a' and 'd')
B2.A1: 0
B1.A2: 1 ('f')
B2.A2: 1 ('f')
B1.A3: 3 ('k' and 'o')
.
.
.
B2.A5: 0
```

Thank you a lot!
Tomi

Comment: wow. Um. formatting. and also, you need to post your code. This is difficult to answer unless we know whether your using straight MySQL, PHP, prepared statements etc

Comment: Any time you have to match across multiple columns like this, it's a strong indicator that your table design is wrong. You should have a table whose primary key is the line# and ABC# or BBC#. Then you can just use a JOIN plus COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select A.Line_A, B.Line_B,
       ((ABC1 = BBC1) +
        (ABC2 = BBC2) +
        (ABC3 = BBC3) +
        (ABC4 = BBC4) +
        (ABC5 = BBC5)
       ) as NumMatching        
from A cross join
     B;
```

The `cross join` generates all pairs of rows.  In MySQL, a boolean result is treated as an integer, with 0 being false and 1 being true.  So the sum of the booleans counts up the number of matching fields.

EDIT:

I notice that the desired result is not pairing the fields.  This makes it a bit more complicated.  If there are no duplicate values or NULLs (as in your sample data), then this works:

```
select A.Line_A, B.Line_B,
       ((ABC1 in (BBC1, BBC2, BBC3, BBC4, BBC5)) +
        (ABC2 in (BBC1, BBC2, BBC3, BBC4, BBC5)) +
        (ABC3 in (BBC1, BBC2, BBC3, BBC4, BBC5)) +
        (ABC4 in (BBC1, BBC2, BBC3, BBC4, BBC5)) +
        (ABC5 in (BBC1, BBC2, BBC3, BBC4, BBC5))
       ) as NumMatching        
from A cross join
     B;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot, it's very useful - however I would like to have the number of matching in a row where column of the word doesn't count. For example: if word "l" in B2 is in column3 and in A3 is in column2, it's also counted as matching.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly! You're my hero!